# Simple SQL Table Insert

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I'm looking to take the data from the query below (all employees in Seattle) and insert it into a new, blank table with identical columns as my select statement.

```
select e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.email, e.phone_number, e.hire_date, e.job_id,       e.salary, e.commission_pct, e.manager_id, e.department_id
from employees e
join departments d
on e.department_id = d.department_id
join jobs j
on e.job_id = j.job_id
join locations l
on d.location_id = l.location_id
where l.city = 'Seattle';
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: it depends on the RDBMS you are using. Each of them has its own syntax

Comment: Indeed, some will have something akin to `CREATE TABLE SeatleEmployees FROM SELECT...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an existing table you can do:

```
INSERT INTO ExistingTable (Columns,..)
SELECT Columns,...
FROM OtherTable
```

From your sql

```
insert into newEmpTable (employee_id, first_name, 
  last_name, email, phone_number, hire_date, 
  job_id, salary, commission_pct, manager_id, department_id)
select e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.email, e.phone_number, e.hire_date, e.job_id,       e.salary, e.commission_pct, e.manager_id, e.department_id
from employees e
join departments d
on e.department_id = d.department_id
join jobs j
on e.job_id = j.job_id
join locations l
on d.location_id = l.location_id
where l.city = 'Seattle';
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/insert-select.html

If you do not have a table and want to create it,

```
create table new_table as 
select e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.email, e.phone_number, e.hire_date,     e.job_id,       e.salary, e.commission_pct, e.manager_id, e.department_id
from employees e
join departments d
on e.department_id = d.department_id
join jobs j
on e.job_id = j.job_id
join locations l
on d.location_id = l.location_id
where l.city = 'Seattle';
```

Comment: When I use INSERT INTO and paste select statement below at the select, I get the error: "SQL Error: ORA-00904: "COMMISSION_PCT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:"

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the datatype of `COMMISION_PCT` in your target table and what is the datatype in your source table? Are they same?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE SeatleEmployees AS
(/* your query here */);
```

Comment: Awesome. Is there a way to insert it into an existing table, though? I've already created constraints, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE VIEW seattleView AS
    /*YOUR SELECT STATEMENT HERE*/;
```

then

```
    CREATE TABLE newTbl AS
    SELECT /*ALL THE COLUMN NAMES*/
    FROM seattleView;
```